# HTML BeginCollectionItem returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

HTML.BeginCollectionItem does not return values to the controller. It always return NULL in the controller. I am not sure if has got anything to do if there is a partial view within another partial view. Below is the snippet of the code/view.

### ProductEditModel

```
 public class ProductEditModel
    {
        // Product details displayed on edit form
        public Product ProductModel { get; set; }
        public IList<ProductAssetAudioEditModel> ProductAssetAudios { get; set;}
    }
```

### ProductAssetAudioEditModel

```
 public class ProductAssetAudioEditModel
 {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int? ProductAssetId { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductAssetResourceEditModel> ProductAssetResources { get; set; }
}
```

### ProductAssetResourceEditModel

```
public class ProductAssetResourceEditModel
    {
        public int? ProductAssetResourceId { get; set; }
        public int ProductAssetId { get; set; }
        public int ResourceNumber { get; set; }
        public int? ElectronicFileId { get; set; }
        public ElectronicFile ElectronicFile { get; set; }
    }
```

### ProductEditView.cshtml

```
<div id="audio">
    @foreach (ProductAssetAudioEditModel audio in Model.ProductAssetAudios)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_ProductAssetAudioRow", audio);
    }
</div>
```

### _ProductAssetAudioRow.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductAssetAudios"))
 {
    ....
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var resource in Model.ProductAssetResources)
        {
           Html.RenderPartial("_ProductAssetAudioResource", resource);    

        }
    </tbody>
    .....
  }
```

### _ProductAssetAudioResource

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductAssetResources"))
 {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ProductAssetResourceId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ProductAssetId)
        <td>
            @if (Model.ElectronicFileId.HasValue)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ElectronicFileId)
                @Html.ActionLink(Model.ElectronicFile.FileName, "Details", "File", new { id = Model.ElectronicFileId, area = "Edi" }, null);
            }
        </td>
        <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(c => Model.TrackTitle)
        </td>
}
```

In the controller , ProductAssetResources is NULL even though edit page binds the properties correctly for editing.

I am not sure what I am missing here.

-Alan-

Comment: `BeginCollectionItem` will not work with nested collections. There is another helper based on `BeginCollectionItem` that appears to be suitable for nested lists (not tested) - refer [this article](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/)

Comment: And are you dynamically adding and removing collection items in the view? (in which case you don't really need `BegnCollectionItem`)